# Calling a RESTful Web Service using FutureTask

Tags: android, multithreading, web-services, future, futuretask

For the time being I am using AsyncHttpClient to call RESTfull WebService from android Device and it is running fine. I want to optimize it using FutureTask as it allows us to check if a thread is finished and stuff. The code I am using now is something like this

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    try {
        client.post(applicationContext, "http://" + ip
                + ":8080/MyWebService/jaxrs/service/getData",
                new StringEntity("String"), "application/json",
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String content) {
                        System.err.println("Exception: "
                                    + e.getMessage());
                    }

                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: "
                                    + e.getMessage());
    }
```

What I know is to make AsyncHttpClient inside **call** function of **Callable < class >**, to call WebService.

Here I am confused as AsyncHttpClient is also running in a thread. How should I call Web Service using **Future**.

**NOTE:**
 - Beginner in Threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Future + HttpClient = AsyncHttpClient

If AsyncHttpClient.onSuccess() or AsyncHttpClient.onFailure() is called, it means the thread is finished, or it's still running(blocked).

==EDIT==

Ok, an example here. Please read more about FutureTask and Executor in java doc.

```
FutureTask<HttpResult> future = new FutureTask<HttpResult>(new Callable<HttpResult>() {
        // GET A HTTP RESULT IN ANOTHER THREAD
        @Override
        public HttpResult call() throws Exception {
            HttpClient httpClient =new HttpClient();
            //set url, http method and params
            HttpResult result = httpClient.getResult(); // sync request, it costs a long time.  
            return result;
        }
    }){
        // FutureTask.DONE() WILL BE CALLED ASYNCHRONOUSLY
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                HttpResult result=get();
                //read the result
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                logger.error("", e);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                logger.error("", e);
            }

        }
    };
```

Comment: But like in Future, how can i send some result back to Caller?

Comment: I read more into it and worked on it and found out if u send back in async task it becomes synch and not async

Comment: @MuneebMirza Do you know the async way to use a FutureTask is `Executor.execute(futureTask)`, which will make it run in another thread. Executor can be constructed by `java.util.concurrent.Executors`.